# Kendo UI Grid (Ajax binding) 500 error when EF6 relationships are setup between tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, telerik-mvc

After hours and hours of troubleshooting I finally narrowed down my problem.
I followed instructions exactly for ajax binding to setup a Kendo UI grid for my Customers entity. Nothing would appear in the grid so I saw that there was a 500 server error and if I navigated directly to /Customers/Customers_Read it would give me the error "This request has been blocked because sensitive information could be disclosed to third party web sites when this is used in a GET request".

As a last resort I deleted all entities that had relationships with my customers table such as CustomerContacts and Address from my EDMX file. The grid binds without any problems at all.

Could someone please tell me what is going on? I am using EF6 DB First and had such a simple model. Maybe I am setting something incorrectly when I set my relationships in SSMS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can not use Ajax to issue cross domain requests. You must use jQuery's $.getJSON() if the url of the request is not on the same domain of your app.

Answer (score 0):

If the request is cross domain you should be able to enable CORS.  You haven't said what type of project you are using.  If it's MVC WebApi it's fairly simple. See:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api